# retrieve information about an event and determine if user is participating - mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I use the query below to retrieve information about a meetup(an event), and now i need to know if the user viewing it is participating in it.

```
SELECT
 meetups.id,
 meetups.meetup_name,
 meetups.url_meetup,
 meetups.meetup_text,
 meetups.date,
 meetups.time,
 users.username,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,users.birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age,
 c1.city_name as meetup_city,
 c2.city_name as user_city   
FROM
 meetups  
 LEFT JOIN users ON
  meetups.author_id=users.id
 LEFT JOIN cities c1 ON
  c1.postalcode = meetups.postalcode
 LEFT JOIN cities c2 ON
  c2.postalcode = users.postalcode
WHERE
 meetups.url_meetup = ?
```

I have a table called meetup_participants where i store the users participating in the different meetups.

The structure of this table is simply:

```
meetup_id, user_id
```

with a unique index on the two cols.

So i need to somehow join the the table on meetups.id = meetup_participants.id, and the user_id will have to be equal the one stored in the session.

I would like to just get the result as either 1, if the user participates, and 0, if he does not.

How can i do this in the select statement (preferably without a subquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a left join to your meetup_participants table.

```
left join meetup_participants mp where mp.something = meetups.something
and mp.user_id = the one you want.
```

Use a case construct in your select clause.

```
case when mp.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end IsParticipant
```

Comment: That seems like what i'm looking for. I will give it a go when i get home.